# Create grid (n × n) in Android ConstraintLayout with variable number of n

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a square grid inside `ConstraintLayout`. My first thought was to create a horizontal chain, give some margin value and set to all single view size attributes `width = match_constraint`, `height = match_constraint` and set the ratio to 1:1. It works and it looks like:

[image]

And it's easy when a size of the grid is 2×2 - there are 4 elements so it's easy. But what I should do when I had to create a grid 7×7? We have 49 views so setting all of these views could be tricky. I want to do this in constraint layout because I want to have a flexible layout. :)

Comment: have you considered using a `RecyclerView` with a span count of 7?

Comment: hmm actually not :) but it's some idea is true. But I'm not sure that it's the best way to handle this problem

Comment: it depends on your needs but I doubt you will fit 49 square views on a single screen at the same time

Comment: thats why a use a "match_constraint" with ratio 1:1 to create a sqare. 7x7 grid is also for example in 2048 game

Comment: Like @Benjamin said, having 49 views on screen is a bad idea. It's a lot of measuring, layout etc. If you're going to display content like images in the squares consider RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager. If you need to create a game board(e.g. a chess board) it's a better solution to have a single custom view and override it's onDraw() and draw some squares yourself. Both solutions would be much faster than having 49 views on the screen at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you say that you have a variable number of squares, I assume that you are willing to create the n*n grid in code. Here is an approach to creating the grid. This is just one way and there are probably others.

First, create a layout with `ConstraintLayout` as the root view. In that layout, define a widget that has width and height of `match_constraints` and is constrained by the parent. This will give you a square widget regardless of the device orientation. (I use a `View` here so it can be seen, but it is better to use a `Space` widget although it probably doesn't really matter.)

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/gridFrame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code for the activity that creates a 7*7 grid. We will use the on-screen view from the layout as the "parent" view to contain the squares.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int mRows = 7;
    int mCols = 7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        int color1 = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        int color2 = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
        TextView textView;
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp;
        int id;
        int idArray[][] = new int[mRows][mCols];
        ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();

        // Add our views to the ConstraintLayout.
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < mRows; iRow++) {
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < mCols; iCol++) {
                textView = new TextView(this);
                lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT,
                                                       ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
                id = View.generateViewId();
                idArray[iRow][iCol] = id;
                textView.setId(id);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(id));
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(((iRow + iCol) % 2 == 0) ? color1 : color2);
                layout.addView(textView, lp);
            }
        }

        // Create horizontal chain for each row and set the 1:1 dimensions.
        // but first make sure the layout frame has the right ratio set.
        cs.clone(layout);
        cs.setDimensionRatio(R.id.gridFrame, mCols + ":" + mRows);
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < mRows; iRow++) {
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < mCols; iCol++) {
                id = idArray[iRow][iCol];
                cs.setDimensionRatio(id, "1:1");
                if (iRow == 0) {
                    // Connect the top row to the top of the frame.
                    cs.connect(id, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.gridFrame, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                } else {
                    // Connect top to bottom of row above.
                    cs.connect(id, ConstraintSet.TOP, idArray[iRow - 1][0], ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
                }
            }
            // Create a horiontal chain that will determine the dimensions of our squares.
            // Could also be createHorizontalChainRtl() with START/END.
            cs.createHorizontalChain(R.id.gridFrame, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                     R.id.gridFrame, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                     idArray[iRow], null, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED);
        }

        cs.applyTo(layout);
    }
}
```

Just change `mRows` and `mCols` and the grid will adjust itself. If your grid will always be square, you will not need to set the ratio of the grid container in the code. You can also place your grid within a more complicated layout. Just make sure that the grid container has the right dimensions and you are good to go.

Comment: It's ver good answer. I jus looking for something like this. Thank you so much! ;)

Comment: Now i saw that is work but there is a problem with performance. My app lag's and i have in logs:
I/Choreographer: Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
When i unccoment this everythink is correct

Comment: @miosz That is a lot of work to do on the main thread. If you are creating the matrix over and over, it may be a problem. If you are doing it once in a while, it shouldn't be a problem. Is this on an emulator? An emulator would be more sensitive than an actual device. I take that you aren't getting an ANR error, so that would also be OK if this is something that is occasionally done.  If performance really is an issue (laggy and noticeable to users) and more then just a logcat complaint, you may want to consider ways to speed things up.

Comment: no is on regular device ( Nexus 5) and I create a matrix once. But yes this peraformance is relly issue (laggy). What do you mean about speed things up? Or do you think create this on other thread could be a good idea? (as post action)

Comment: @miosz Try to get an idea about where the time is being spent. There are some performance measurement tools in Studio that should be able to help. I don't have much experience with these, so I can't help there. You could try moving some work off the main thread, but you have to use the main thread for UI manipulation. You could also consider creating building blocks of 2,3...7... rows in XML and use code to add and interlink these. Just some ideas, but measurement will be the key; otherwise, you may just spin your wheels.

Comment: I'll try to do it only in xml. Just put it manually (yes it wasn't nice job), and I also have some lags and skipped frames. So i think that constraintlayout is not god layout to implement grid :(

Answer (score 0):

Best idea is to create two views linear layouts, one that has horizontalAlignment and Another that has vertical alignment.
Group with vertical alignment is one that you call in your layout and pass to it as an attribute a number(7).
This group will add horizontal group 7 times to itself. Each horizontal layout will in-turn take a number (7) again. And that will add 7 squares.
Trick is to see that each square will have same weight. And each horizontal row will have same weight. That way u will get grids of right size provides you insert Verical layout in square ViewGroup

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right I think the best way is to use the Flow widget

```
androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
```

and put the id of all views which should be included in the grid in the following field:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids
```

more info can be found here:

https://bignerdranch.com/blog/constraintlayout-flow-simple-grid-building-without-nested-layouts/